# How do I split a string with a limit starting by the right in java?

Tags: java, regex, split

Split without limits split the entire string but if you set a limit it splits up to that limit by the left. How can I do the same by the right?

```
"a.b.c".split("[.]", 2); // returns ["a", "b.c"]
```

I would want

```
"a.b.c".splitRight("[.]", 2); // to return ["a.b", "c"]
```

EDIT: I want a general solution that works just like splited but reversed so I add a more complex example

I would want

```
"a(->)b(->)c(->)d".splitRight("\\(->\\)", 3); // to return ["a(->)b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: @blank :D Funny solution but there is too much computation work there and if the separator is not a single character I would have to reverse it too...

Comment: too much computation? we have computers for this kind of stuff! but yes it does become more complicated

Comment: @blank Imagine you have to do it 100000 times per second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try with something like this:

```
public List<String> splitRight(String string, String regex, int limit) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] temp = new String[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
        if(string.matches(".*"+regex+".*")) {
            temp = string.split(modifyRegex(regex));
            result.add(temp[1]);
            string = temp[0];
        }
    }
    if(temp.length>0) { 
        result.add(temp[0]);
    }
    Collections.reverse(result);
    return result;
}

public String modifyRegex(String regex){
    return regex + "(?!.*" + regex + ".*$)";
}
```

The regular expression for split is wrapped by another, so for `\\.`, you will get: `\\.(?!.*\\..*$)`, to match and split on last occurance of delimiter. The string is splitted multiple time with this regex, the second element of result array is added to List, next split is done on first element of result array.

The effect of above method for your example string is as expected.

Answer (score 6):

You may use look-ahead match:

```
"a.b.c".split("[.](?=[^.]*$)")
```

Here you say "I want to split by only that dot which has no other dots after it".

If you want to split by last N dots, you can generalize this solution in this (even more ugly way):

```
"dfsga.sdgdsb.dsgc.dsgsdfg.dsdg.sdfg.sdf".split("[.](?=([^.]*[.]){0,3}[^.]*$)");
```

Replace `3` with `N-2`.

However I would write a short static method instead:

```
public static String[] splitAtLastDot(String s) {
    int pos = s.lastIndexOf('.');
    if(pos == -1)
        return new String[] {s};
    return new String[] {s.substring(0, pos), s.substring(pos+1)};
}
```

Comment: Nice solution if the limit is 2. Any variant to allow it to be a parameter? I don't mind including somethink like `{2}` in the regex string. And the regex is specific for that separator. It is not so easy to adapt it to any separator. Thank you

Comment: I did just that `splitAtLastDot` but I wondered if there is a general solution, not just for the limit 2 case.

Answer (score 2):

Despite that you said reversing would take to long, here´s a small programm that reveres the String and splits it by the limit;

```
static String[] leftSplit(String input, String regex, int limit) {
    String reveresedInput = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();
    String[] output = reveresedInput.split(regex, limit);
    String tempOutput[] = new String[output.length];
    for(int i = 0;i<output.length;++i) {
        tempOutput[tempOutput.length-i-1] = new StringBuilder(output[i]).reverse().toString();
    }
    return tempOutput;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(leftSplit("a.b.c", "[.]", 2)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(leftSplit("I want to. Split this. by the. right side", "[.]", 2)));
}
```

Comment: That would not work if the regex is directional like `"-->"` and you can't always reverse a regex.

Comment: Yeah, this wont work on a more complex regex, but for a more simple regex this should work. To make it work for a complex regex you would have to reverse the regex aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Performance isn't good but readability is better than some of examples above:

```
List l = Arrays.stream(new StringBuilder("a.b.c").reverse().toString().split("\\.", 2))
.map(StringBuilder::new).map(StringBuilder::reverse).collect(toList());
Collections.reverse(l);
```

Comment: Hi. In the last example it would not work this way as "->" and "<-" are two different things. You would need to reverse the split regex too and that's not always easy.

Comment: @aalku, we can reverse regexp as well `"\\)>-\\("`, it looks ugly but works